# Horizontal Bar (Dashboard) in the Lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, custom

I have one requirement to use Dashboard in the custom component to show Horizontal Bars based on some data. The condition is it only need to show the horizontal bars from salesforce title and header footer will be customized.

I used chart.js to implement this which is working fine when locker services are deactivated but if I activate locker services it stops working.

Please give me quick suggerstions.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Which version of ChartJS are you using? See https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/02/lockerservice-lightning-container-third-party-libraries-lightning-components.html.

Version 2.1.4 is known to work with Locker. Let us know if that's not what you experience.